# TFS disables "Merge changes in Merge tool" option

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs, merge

I am using TFS 2012.But in visual studio 2008 If there any conflicts during chekin or get lasest version it displays several option like merge in merge tool, overwrite local, keep server etc.  But sometimes i don't get `merge changes for me` and `merge changes in merge tool` option and they are disabled. I tried to find the reason behind it but didn't get exactly when this happens. Regularly I do get all options enabled. So when these options are disabled? And how exactly this conflicts can be solved?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I assume that for .frm file type the merge is not enabled. You can enable it by right clicking on the server in Team Explorer, Team Foundation Server Settings and from there select Source Control File Types. There you need to enable .frm extensions.

Comment: Ok. frm extensions was not there. But sometimes i do get merge changes for me and merge changes in merge tool option for .frm files. So how is it possible? From where those option came?